# Android Database NullPointerException when opening a second time

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been having an issue with refreshing the list of contacts for a fragment, every time I try to call a method which refreshes the list, I get this error:

```
01-11 17:55:48.215: W/System.err(25594): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594):at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at com.Spit.pocketbook.DatabaseManager.<init>(DatabaseManager.java:48)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at com.Spit.pocketbook.ContactsFragment.getContacts(ContactsFragment.java:105)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at com.Spit.pocketbook.ContactsFragment.fillContactList(ContactsFragment.java:70)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at com.Spit.pocketbook.SwipeActivity.onFinishCreateContactDailog(SwipeActivity.java:96)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at com.Spit.pocketbook.ContactCreateDialog$PositiveButtonListener.onClick(ContactCreateDialog.java:129)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 17:55:48.235: W/System.err(25594): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 17:55:48.245: W/System.err(25594): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-11 17:55:48.245: W/System.err(25594): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-11 17:55:48.245: W/System.err(25594): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So this happens every time I use this method in the ContactsFragment

```
private ArrayList<Contact> getContacts(){
    DatabaseManager manager = new DatabaseManager(getActivity());
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = manager.getAllContacts();
    manager.close();
    return contacts;
}
```

which instantiates a new DatabaseManager (which I created to do the grunt work in the database and wrap it up nicely for the rest of my app):

```
public DatabaseManager(Context context){
    mDatabase = new DatabaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();    //Line 48 (where the error occurs)
    mContext = context;
}
```

and here is the `getAllContacts()` method for reference:

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getAllContacts(){
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    //query the database for all the contacts
    String[] projections = {ContactsTable._ID, 
            ContactsTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, 
            ContactsTable.COLUMN_LOOKUP_KEY,
            ContactsTable.COLUMN_SCOPE};
    Cursor C = mDatabase.query(ContactsTable.CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, projections, 
            null, null, null, null, ContactsTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " ASC");

    //iterates through the results and adds them all to the ArrayList
    while(C.moveToNext()){
        Contact contact = new Contact(C.getLong(0),
                C.getString(1),
                C.getString(2),
                C.getString(3));
        contacts.add(contact);
        }

    C.close();  //save from memory leakage

    return contacts;
}
```

Note: the "m" variables represent global variables

The interesting part in all of this is that this very same method (`.getContacts()`) is called when the ContactFragment is created which also calls the DatabaseManager constructor the very same way. In addition to all of this, when my app loads up it opens up a ViewPager (SwipeActivity for those who actually read the log) which loads up two fragments. The ContactsFragment and another SummaryFragment which uses a very similar method to `.getContact()` to get other information in the database. But my app works well when it loads up. All the information is fetched and gets displayed just fine. Only when I try updating it a second time in either fragments lifetime I will get and error. The only fix I've found to this is to rotate the screen which basically dumps and recreates everything in the Activity.

Because it works when I rotate the screen, this leads me to think that it's an issue with the fact that even though I closed the database, it somehow stays open and that's why I can't call it a second time to refresh the lists. If this is the issue I have no idea how to fix it and would appreciate any and all help on that, but then again, this may have nothing to do with it.

Here is my call to `manager.close()` which closes the database that the DatabaseManager opens when it is created:

```
public void close(){
    mDatabase.close();
}
```

I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now. I've done some research (with no avail obviously) and looked at different ways the bug could be produced but every fix I come up with has no effect.

Thanks ahead of time for any and all advice/help,

David (Spit)

Comment: Sorry I know this isn't an answer, but I would strongly consider refactoring this code. You're making a database query on the UI thread which is a big no-no. You're also passing around an Activity which is just asking for a memory leak. You should use the Loader APIs (I like having my Fragments implement the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface), which takes care of not only the threading issue, but also handles opening/closing the database, which will solve the exception you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because you closed the database and then subsequent attempts to re-open it are failing for some reason.

Your best bet is to not close the database. As Google FW engineer Dianne Hackborn says, you don't need to close the database manually since it will automatically be closed once your Process is killed. Refer to [link #1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/NwDRpHUXt0U/jIam4Q8-cqQJ) and [link #2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/DAkbe6rzxXY) for multiple posts where she comments on this.

Also, if you DO go along this path, you should make your `DatabaseHelper` a singleton, so that you only have one instance of the DB at any one time (otherwise that, too, would become problematic). Implement something like this for your `ContentProvider` and nested `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
public class CustomDbProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myapp.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String TAG = "DBHelper";
        private static DatabaseHelper sInstance = null;

        private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

            // calls the super constructor, requesting the default cursor factory.
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context c) {
            if (sInstance == null) sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(c);
            return sInstance;
        }
```

And then your `Fragment` you can do the following (see also [dev page here](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html)) (Also, this code assumes you're using some type of `List` and `Adapter` but if not, once you get the `Cursor` in `onLoadFinished()` you can do whatever you need to with it):

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        ...
        // initialize the loader with the loader callbacks
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(SOME_UNIQUE_ID, getArguments(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle fragargs) {
        Uri uri = /* FIXME some URL defined in your Provider */;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        return new CursorLoader(mContext, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, ContactsTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " ASC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

Comment: Hmm that's what I was thinking was the problem too. But I think it's worth trying what @Sam_D said in the comment to my post, because I feel the knowledge would serve me well in the future. Thanks for your suggestion though, it's much appreciated.

Comment: It's possible you may need both. Typically I use the DbHelper Singleton in my ContentProvider and then use the CursorLoader for querying for the Cursor needed.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I guess I was going to implement a similar method. Would you happen to have some example code laying around to get me started on this, since clearly I haven't really used this method before. In particular, I'm having trouble understanding how to set the loader's observer on the data (my data comes from a personal database and all I seen when I search is the android database).

Comment: Yes I'll put something together and update my answer.

Comment: Ok I have one last question. Where would you instantiate the Database using the `DatabaseHelper.getInstance()` method? I ask this because I read on  the [Creating a Content Provider # Implementing the onCreate() method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#OnCreate) and it said to never instantiate the database in the `onCreate()` method, rather instantiate the `DatabaseHelper` there and the Database when needed. I'm curious as to where to put mine since your method skips the instantiation of `DatabaseHelper`.

Comment: Right, so the database is created anywhere in your ContentProvider only where you need it, which is typically in the standard 4 methods: insert(), update(), delete(), query(). You would call `DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getContext()).getWritableDatabase();` You won't really need to access it most other places unless you start making really complex SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says that the context you passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` is `null`.

Since it's fragment `getActivity()` you're passing as context, the fragment wasn't attached to  an activity at the time your database manager was created.

Comment: I looked into this and I don't believe it's the issue because when I try to make a work around that would solve the issue (more like a test to see if that was the issue) there was no affect.